# Terraform setting Elastic beanstalk solution stack version to 0.1.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I used terraform to create my elastic beanstalk application and get it all setup.  But the version of the solution stack shows as 0.1.0.  Specifically "IIS 8.5 running on 64bit Windows Server Core 2012 R2/0.1.0"  and in the AWS console it suggests I change it. The latest is 2.5.8.

This old version doesn't handle ebextensions very well and deploys fail. If I manually change it in the aws console then deploys work.  But if I run terraform again it changes it back to 0.1.0.

I can't find any way to control that version in terraform.  But really I just want it to be the latest available at the time of creation, which would make sense as a default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provide any terraform code, but normally you would specify version in your [aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_environment).

For example:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "tfenvtest" {

  solution_stack_name = "64bit Windows Server 2019 v2.5.8 running IIS 10.0 "

  # other settings

}
```

The older version you mention is no longer supported for new environments. It was valid until [27 June 2020](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history-dotnet.html).

Comment: Thtat's the name.  But not the version.  In the console you will see "'64bit Windows Server Core 2012 R2 running IIS 8.5/2.5.8'"  But if you put that in as the name you get an error  * 
  aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.dcp_website: InvalidParameterValue: No Solution Stack named '64bit Windows Server Core 2012 R2 running IIS 8.5/2.5.8' found."    You have to strip off the version to get it to work.  But then it creates it with version 0.1.0

Comment: @Randell I updated the answer. In short, the version you are after is no longer available. It ceased on 27 June 2020.

Comment: Not sure which version you mean.  2.5.8 is the latest version... and 2.5.8 is what I was trying to get it to be.  But without a version in the stack name it got created as the oldest version, 0.1.0.  That said... from your updated code, I can see you put a v2.5.8 in the middle of the name, not at the end... which is the magic key.  Not sure why the middle versus the end, when the aws console shows it at the end... but it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @Randell Thanks for letting me know, and glad it worked out :-)